# Loading CoreData in function SwiftUI, with NSFetchRequest Error

Tags: swiftui, nsfetchrequest, fetchrequest

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreData

//MARK: - Welcome View
struct fetchView: View {
    
    
    //MARK: - View
    var body: some View {
        let testing = getFetch()
        ForEach(testing) {test in
            
        }
        Text("Hello World")
    }
    
    //MARK: - Methods
    
    func getFetch() -> NSFetchRequest<FeedList> {
        let fr: NSFetchRequest<FeedList> = NSFetchRequest<FeedList>(entityName: "timestamp")
        fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
        fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp > %@", Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate)
        return fr
    }
}

//MARK: - Preview
struct fetchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        fetchView()
    }
}
```

In the Line ForEach(testing) *(with the t of testing underlined red)* I get the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest' to expected
> argument type 'Range'

If someone knows how to fix this so I can list out the data in my CoreData via. a function that would be a great help.

P.S. I know how to do a @fetchRequest but I am trying to do this so it works in a class where everyday I can total values and put them in an array and @fetchRequest only works in a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the fetch request from that function. What you need to do is return the fetched result (array of type `FeedList`), by calling fetch function on managed object context and passing in the fetchRequest that you made.